# Django forms: default value if user leaves field blank

Tags: django, django-forms

On Django Forms, how do I specify a default value for a field if the user leaves it blank? Initial sets an initial value, but the user can delete this.

Comment: I think you should set a default value in the model

Comment: You can deal with in the field validation(clean_fieldname) method. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/

Comment: Thanks, clean_fieldname seems to be the way to go. Was hoping there was a way to specify it when I defined the field, but I guess not.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you're using a `ModelForm` simply follow Dan's advice.

If however you're simply using a `Form` then you may have to specify how to deal with validation. [Example Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute)

```
class YourForm(forms.Form):
    ...

    def clean_field(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data['field']
        if not data:
            data = 'default value'

        return data
```

Comment: `def clean_field(self): return self.cleaned_data['field'] or 'default value'`

Answer (score 6):

[Set a default value in the model.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#default)

```
class YourModel(models.Model):
    this_field = models.TextField(default="default_value")
```

Comment: I tried forms.CharField(default = "0") and got an error message: "__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'default'"

Comment: Add it to the actual model, not in the form. Your model would be in `models.py`. This way whenever you save a copy of the model - in your example via your form - the default value will be added to that model if it is left blank. I think this is a better solution than via field validation especially if you are going to allow use of the Admin.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. Yes, that would work except my form and model don't quite match up. The form fields are all rows in the same column.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. You must be saving to an instance of the model, so the default value should work. Can you post your code?

Comment: I actually process the data before insertion. I turn each field into a style_name, style_value pair and insert these as separate rows. But I think your answer is actually right for 'normal' cases where there is a model.

Comment: OP asked for forms, not for a model. This doesn't work if the user wants to use the forms and not the model

Answer (score 0):

WallyBay's answer works for me. 
(+adding my experience)

If you leave the form field empty, **None** value will be passed. 
you can check this by printing out from.cleaned_data().

But, in my case, None value wasn't replaced with the Model's default value.

I tested by creating objects in the shell('python manage.py shell') 
passing **1)None value** and **2)empty parameter**.

My Model:

```
class Cart(models.Model):
    total_amount = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=1000, default=1, blank=True, null=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1, blank=True)
    note = models.CharField(max_length=300, default='nothing to mention')
    summery = models.TextField(blank=False, null=True)
    event_won = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

My Form:

```
class CartForm(forms.ModelForm):
    summery = forms.CharField() 
    total_amount = forms.DecimalField(required=False)
    quantity = forms.IntegerField(initial=20)
    note = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={"placeholder":"write a note"}))

    class Meta: 
        model = Cart 
        fields = [
            'summery',
            'total_amount',
            'quantity',
            'note'
        ]
```

1) create the object by passing None value. 
`Cart.objects.create(total_amount=None)`

> Result: Default value didn't apply. The total_amount is Null(None).

2) create the object without passing any. 
`Cart.objects.create()`

> Result: default value worked. total_amount is 1.

When I delete null=True option for the total_amount in the Model class, it gives me an error 'NOT NULL constraint failed'